# Make the ul li behave like a SELECT

Tags: jquery

I have a database transaction with an option value. What can I do so that the select option value is not empty when I click on the ul li tag?

Following my code:

```js
$('.selected-change li').click(function () {
  $('#city').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
  //console.log($(this).text())
});


$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {

  allOptions.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
  allOptions.toggle();
});
```

```css
#city{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
ul {
   height: 30px;
   width: 150px;
   border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li {padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; list-style:none;}
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city">
  <option value="1">City - 1</option>
  <option value="2">City - 2</option>
  <option value="3">City - 3</option>
</select>
<ul class="selected-change list-unstyled">
  <li class="init">Select</li>
  <li data-val="1">City - 1</li>
  <li data-val="2">City - 2</li>
  <li data-val="3">City - 3</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you advance.

Comment: This will probably fix it: ```$('.selected-change li:not(.init)').click(function () {
  $('#city').val($(this).data('val'));
});```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is the first `li` is clicked and it doesn't have a value but you're trying to change the select menu with it anyways. Just specify you want the listener to only apply to `li` elements that have `data-val` attributes.

`$('.selected-change li[data-val]')...`

```js
$('.selected-change li[data-val]').click(function () {
  $('#city').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
});


$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
  $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
  allOptions.removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
  allOptions.toggle();
});
```

```css
#city{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}
ul {
   height: 30px;
   width: 150px;
   border: 1px #000 solid;
}
ul li {padding: 5px 10px; z-index: 2; }
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; list-style:none;}
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city">
  <option value="1">City - 1</option>
  <option value="2">City - 2</option>
  <option value="3">City - 3</option>
</select>
<ul class="selected-change list-unstyled">
  <li class="init">Select</li>
  <li data-val="1">City - 1</li>
  <li data-val="2">City - 2</li>
  <li data-val="3">City - 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simplest "ul select" I found.  It's needed because option tags allow only text, but list item tags let you put in div's and other complex constructions.  I had to a z-index value to the ul because text from a subsequent control was showing through the the li dropdowns.  All in all, a very useful starting point for making a select from a ul.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you can...

1. Erase this function completely, because it is responsible for clearing the selected option text.

```
$('.selected-change li').click(function () {
   $('#city').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
   //console.log($(this).text())
});
```

2. Then, move the `$('#city')` code from above into the below function...

```
var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
   allOptions.removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
   allOptions.toggle();
   $('#city').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change'); // <-- move here
});
```

Based on that change, the selected option only changes after clicking the list items which is what I think you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

For that I achieve something simple that you can use with otherwise or proceed as the answers above, which are working and are functional.

With event click, event change and data of the UL, I managed to get the needed behaviour.

Follow me here:

```js
$('body').on('click','ul#demo', function(e){
        const selectedId = e.target.id 
        const newText = $(e.target).text()
        
        if (e.target.tagName != 'LI') {return} //checkup if you didn't click UL element itself
        
        $('ul#demo').text(newText).trigger('change')
    })

    $('body').on('change','ul#demo', async function(e){
        //once you change the text, you'll inevitably destroy all LI within UL
        const rebuildList = GetYourListData() //preferably an json object
        
        $.each(rebuildList, function (index, value) { 
            //appending the data to the same UL
            //I used id as Index, you can use as you wish
            
            $('ul#demo').append(
                `<li id="${index}"`+
                `>${value.text}</li>`
            );
        });
    })

    function GetYourListData() {
      let yourOldDataAsJSON = '{"1": {"text":"Item 1"},"2":{"text":"Item 2"},"3":{"text":"Item 3"}}'
      return JSON.parse(yourOldDataAsJSON)
    }
```

```css
.select {
        /* display: inline-flex; */
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        position: relative;

        /* width: 50%; */
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px;

        border-radius: 5px;
        outline: 1px solid rgb(71, 71, 71);

        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .select:hover {
        background-color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        font-weight: bold;

        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .select:hover li {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        box-sizing: border-box;

        visibility: visible;

        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: normal;

        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;

        border-radius: 5px;

        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .select li {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative;

        visibility: collapse;

        color: white;
        font-size: 0px;
        font-weight: normal;

        height: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;

        border-radius: 0px;

        transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .select li:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: rgb(71, 71, 71);
        font-weight: normal;

        cursor: pointer;

        transition: all 0.3s;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="demo" class="select">Choose!!
      <li id="1">Item 1</li>
      <li id="2">Item 2</li>
      <li id="3">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Please, also note the CSS classes, they are necessary, you can absolutely change the HOVER by ACTIVE if you want to click before the LI elements showing up.

Hope it finds you well and helps you out!